# What is the cause of my EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code = 2) Error?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am a very novice programmer and am to trying to create an Xcode app that gives the user a random meal based on the parameters they set. I have no idea whether I have set it up right in the first place. Currently it just functions to change a label to the name of a meal based on the  parameters set, after checking if it is applicable but have been getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code = 2) error when I click the button "selectRandomMealSelection".

I am open to any criticism but please go easy on me as I've only be learning for about a month off the internet and still not 100% sure how it all works. Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

init(attr0: Bool, attr1: Bool, attr2: Bool, attr3: Bool, attr4: Bool, attr5: Bool, randomMealCaseNumber: Int, cuisine: [String])
{
    self.attr0 = attr0
    self.attr1 = attr1
    self.attr2 = attr2
    self.attr3 = attr3
    self.attr4 = attr4
    self.attr5 = attr5
    self.randomMealCaseNumber = randomMealCaseNumber
    self.cuisine = cuisine

    super.init()
}


required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

var cuisine = ["Chinese", "Indian"]

@IBOutlet var healthSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet var easeSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet var timeSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet var costSwitch: UISwitch!

var attr0 = true            //Chinese
var attr1 = false           //Indian
var attr2 = false           //Health
var attr3 = false           //Ease
var attr4 = false           //Time Sensitivity
var attr5 = false           //Cost Sensitivity


@IBOutlet var mealNameLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func healthIsRelevant(sender: UISwitch) {
    if healthSwitch.on == true{
        attr2 = true
    }
    else if healthSwitch.on == false {
        attr2 = false
    }
}

@IBAction func easeIsRelevant(sender: UISwitch) {
    if easeSwitch.on == true {
        attr3 = true
    }
    else if easeSwitch.on == false {
        attr3 = false
    }
}

@IBAction func timeIsRelevant(sender: UISwitch) {
    if timeSwitch.on == true {
        attr4 = true
    }
    else if timeSwitch.on == false {
        attr4 = false
    }
}

@IBAction func costIsRelevent(sender: UISwitch) {
    if costSwitch.on == true {
        attr5 = true
    }
    else if costSwitch.on == false {
        attr5 = false
    }
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    return cuisine.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String
{
    return cuisine[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    var cuisineSelected = "\(cuisine[row])"

    if cuisineSelected == cuisine[0] {
        attr0 = true
        attr1 = false
    }
    else if cuisineSelected == cuisine[1] {
        attr0 = false
        attr1 = true
    }
}

let PorkChowMeinNoodles = (true, false, false, true, false, true)
func porkChowMeinNoodles (name: UILabel) {
    name.text = "Pork Chow Mein Noodles"
}
let ButterChicken = (false, true, false, false, false, false)
func butterChicken (name: UILabel) {
    name.text = "Butter Chicken"
}

var x = 0

var randomMealCaseNumber: Int = Int(arc4random() % 2)

@IBAction func selectRandomMealSelection(sender: UIButton) {
    randomMealSelection()


}

func randomMealSelection () {

    var randomMealCaseNumber: Int = Int(arc4random() % 2)

    switch (randomMealCaseNumber) {
    case 0:
        applicabilityTest(ButterChicken, a: attr0 ,b: attr1 ,c: attr2 ,d: attr3,e: attr4,f: attr5)
        if x == 1 {
            butterChicken(mealNameLabel)
        }
        else if x == 0 {
            randomMealSelection()
        }
    case 1:
        applicabilityTest(PorkChowMeinNoodles, a: attr0 ,b: attr1 ,c: attr2 ,d: attr3,e: attr4,f: attr5)
        if x == 1 {
            porkChowMeinNoodles(mealNameLabel)
        }
        else if x == 0 {
            randomMealSelection()
        }
    default:
        break;
    }
}

func applicabilityTest (meal: (Bool,Bool,Bool,Bool,Bool,Bool), a: Bool, b: Bool, c: Bool, d: Bool, e: Bool, f: Bool) {
    var a = attr0
    var b = attr1
    var c = attr2
    var d = attr3
    var e = attr4
    var f = attr5

    if meal.0 == a {
        if meal.1 == b {
            if meal.2 == c {
                if meal.3 == d {
                    if meal.4 == e {
                        if meal.5 == f {
                            x += 1
                        }
                        else
                        {x += 0}
                    }
                    else
                    {x += 0}
                }
                else
                {x += 0}
            }
            else
            {x += 0}
        }
        else
        {x += 0}
    }
    else
    {x += 0}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to *debug* the problem? Set a breakpoint on the selectRandomMealSelection function, single-step through the code, etc ... to isolate your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add where the problem is, it starts at the first line of the applicabilityTest function. @MartinR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method

```
init(attr0: Bool, attr1: Bool, attr2: Bool, attr3: Bool, attr4: Bool, attr5: Bool, randomMealCaseNumber: Int, cuisine: [String])
```

is never called.  Place this logic within the `viewDidLoad` method.  A `ViewController`'s object life-cycle (`init` &  `dealloc`) is controlled by UIKit.  In general, you should not use these methods for your code logic.

---

[Edit]

```
setupData(attr0: Bool, attr1: Bool, attr2: Bool, attr3: Bool, attr4: Bool, attr5: Bool, randomMealCaseNumber: Int, cuisine: [String])
{
    self.attr0 = attr0
    self.attr1 = attr1
    self.attr2 = attr2
    self.attr3 = attr3
    self.attr4 = attr4
    self.attr5 = attr5
    self.randomMealCaseNumber = randomMealCaseNumber
    self.cuisine = cuisine
}
```

And then call `setupData(....)` from wherever you present this view controller (in the prepare for segue or `presetViewController`)

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. I put the initializer in the viewDidLoad and it returns a compiler error: "Initializers may only be declared within a type"  @StephenFurlani

Comment: Don't call `init()` at all

Answer (score -1):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code = 2) occurs when an object is called after it is deallocated from the memory. Make sure that you are not releasing any object's memory before you are calling it.

I think your "attr0" may be causing problems.

In your viewdidload, try writing super.init() before everything else. It should work.

Comment: Calling `super.init()` in `viewDidLoad` is likely to cause many other issues.

Comment: ohh i am sorry... i meant to say call super.init() in your init function. Sorry, it was typographical error

Comment: That didn't fix it. @RajatSharma